# How I can remove date time metadata from my LibreOffice comments?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, word-documents

Is there a way to control the metadata that is saved in a LibreOffice document? I want to:

- Add comments of my own.
- Prevent date and time metadata from being saved.

Answer (score 1):

[From version 7.2 on](https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/658e947b699ad1e08810f0fefd5c901e750ad919%5E%21), LibreOffice overwrites timestamps and author names on saving documents with versioning enabled. To enable this behavior, click the **Tools ▸ Options** menu and, in the Options dialog, navigate to the **LibreOffice ▸ Security** category. In the **Security Options
and Warnings** area, click **Options…**. Finally, in the dialog that opens, check the **Remove personal information on saving** box.